# Scrapy - Invoke a new crawling process when a crawler finishes

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I search for urls - xxx.com/a, xxx.com/b etc as found from two start_urls xxx.com/LISTA and xxx/com/LISTB

Once this crawler has finished I want to also additionally crawl pages xxx.com/x_in_database and xxx.com/y_in_database - whose URLs were already crawled in a previous crawl in database (and hence available now) but only if the current crawler didn't find them already in LISTA and LISTB

What is the best way to do it? It seems that I can't start a new crawl from `scrapy.signals.spider_closed(spider, reason)` but only do other routine operations like close connections, release resource etc

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is actually the default behavior. If you always explicitly include xxx.com/x_in_database and xxx.com/y_in_database in your list of initial requests, and make sure `Request.dont_filter` is False (the default) it should be automatically de-duped - assuming the header and request body is the same for both requests.

Comment: Isn't the de-duping done on a per session basis?